# Java ArrayPointStoreException and NullPointerException

Tags: java

This is my code. A simple demonstration of method overriding.

```
public class Bond {
   void display() {
      System.out.println("Bond");
   }
}    

public class ConvertibleBond extends Bond {
   void display() {
      System.out.println("ConvertibleBond");
   }
}

public class Pg177E2 {
   public static void main(String[]args) {
         int random = (int)(10*Math.random());
         Bond bond[] = new ConvertibleBond[6];
         for(int i = 0; i < 6 ;i++) {
            if(random < 5) {
               bond[i] = new Bond(); // the problem occurs here
         } else if(random > 5) {
              bond[i] = new ConvertibleBond();
         }
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         bond[i].display();
      }
   }
}
```

This would be simple enough and it should work; however, it is coming up as an `ArrayPointStoreException` and `NullPointerException`. Can anyone please help me out? I have no idea what I did wrong. Everything looks placed in order. The classes are all in the same package.

Comment: **Always** show the exception messages and note for us which line causes them.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: True, but OP marked the error location in a comment...

Comment: I assume you mean "ArrayStoreException": an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Bond bond[] = new ConvertibleBond[6];    
 bond[i] = new Bond();
```

You have an array of ConvertibleBond. It can only take instances of that, not any old Bond.

You probably wanted

```
 Bond bond[] = new Bond[6];
```

Comment: instances of that or subclasses, an example with Animal Dog and Cat would be great :D